# Buscar la fecha menor de un campo de una tabla

Tags: vbscript

Tengo una tabla con campo de fechas quiero que me devuelva la fecha mínima.

tengo esto

```
Dim sql,numCur, Returnedvalue, DesdeFechaSQL, HastaFechaSQL, StopTime,Total_minDate
DesdeFechaSQL= "2023-07-22 6:45:00.000"
HastaFechaSQL= "2023-07-22 15:45:00.000"

sql= "select min ([Tiempo (Incio de Parada)]) as [Tiempo (Incio de Parada)] from [Table_STOPMaquinas] WHERE [Tiempo (Incio de Parada)] >="&" ' "&DesdeFechaSQL&" ' "&"And [Tiempo (Final de Parada)] <="&" ' "Hasta_FechaSQL&" ' "&""
numCur= DBCursorOpenSQL("Base Datos SQL",sql)
Total_minDate =DBCursorGetValue(numCur,"[Tiempo (Incio de Parada)]")
DBCursorClose(numCur)
MsgBox(Total_minDate)
```

Que me devuelva la fecha mínima registrada en la table de ese campo

Answer (score 0):

El error

```
Total_minDate =DBCursorGetValue(numCur,"[Tiempo (Incio de Parada)]")
```

Debiera ser

```
Total_minDate =DBCursorGetValue(numCur,"Tiempo (Incio de Parada)")
```